# QGIS - how to use geometry generator to place a centroid in each segment of a multiline?

Tags: qgis, line, expression, centroids, geometry-generator

With geometry generator in QGIS I'm trying to place a marker in the midpoint of each segment of a multiline vector (I don't want to use the Highlight line option).
My main issue is how to read each line of a multiline separately and have a centroid of each segment.

[image: code example I am trying with]

This is the result, as you can see I get a centroid of the multiline and not one for each segment. I am missing something!

[image: output]

I want to do this within the geometry generator so that anytime I move the line, the midpoint moves accordingly. And once I know how to code `<<make a point>>` I can use the `<<raster_value>>` command and apply that information to the marker.
I could use the "highlight_line" vector stile, and place a marker in the midpoint of each segment, but I would still need to have a point to read the raster below. And I want this to happen automatically and not by modifying the type of vector.

Comment: A multiline would be multiple lines merged into one feature. Your line looks like a normal line. What is wrong with using a marker line and placing the markers on the middle of each segment?

Comment: Nothing wrong with placing a marker in middle of each segment, but I also need to read the value of a raster in that specific midpoint and apply it to the marker's rotation. That is why I need to write the code to retrieve that node.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the following expression for Geometry Generator.

```
with_variable(
    'segments', segments_to_lines($geometry),
    
    collect_geometries(
        array_foreach(
            generate_series(1, num_geometries(@segments)),
            centroid(
                geometry_n(
                    @segments,
                    @element)))))
```

[image]

Or a simpler way is to use "Marker Line" instead of "Geometry Generator" and select `on central point of segments`. (thanks to @Eric)

[image]

Comment: This actually is already available when choosing a marker line.

Comment: @Erik thanks for reminding. I've added a geometry generator solution since Francesco used it. But of course, Marker Line is a shorter way than Geometry Generator.

Comment: Thank you! your code works perfectly! Now I have a marker in the centroid of each segment. I thought that this code would also work when trying to set the rotation of the marker by using the raster_value command

raster_value(layer,band,point)