Labeling each sub-part of multi-part geometry with its part number using QGIS
I want to label each sub-part of a multi-part geometry with its part number shown using Identify -> Derived.
In Layer Styling there is the variable geometry_part_num available as used like in this example, but not in Labeling.
I already enabled “Label every part of multi-part features“.

When you open  Layer Styling or Layer Properties and click on the "Label". Do you see "single Label" or "Rule Based Labeling"?  What are your selection choices when you click on the down arrow of the select box for "Values"?

I don't think you can label each part of a multi polygon seperatly

Please, do not forget about "What should I do when someone answers my question?"

In case your "labels" do not have to be real labels, I have following solution:

Duplicate your MultiPolygon layer to get a layer for the labelling of
the parts (had problems doing the following within the original
layer. Has also the benefit that you do not need to change anything
on your original layer)

Change the Symbology from Simple Fill to Geometry generator. Set
Geometry type to Point / Multipoint

In the    code field, insert
collect_geometries(
    array_foreach(
        geometries_to_array($geometry), -- make array from each MultiPolygon
        make_point(x(@element),         -- make points (centroids) for each part
                   y(@element))))


Change Simple Marker to Font Marker

At Character(s), click on the the drawer box at the right of the
input field and select Edit...

In the opening Expression Builder, insert
@geometry_part_num



Inspired by:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/414531
https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/454627
https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/334487
Apart from this possibility (I love QGIS!), I would rather avoid dealing with multipart objects if possible and solve these issues database-wise (common parent-ids for sub-parts). I can't see any benefit in this stuff.
